# Is there a C# equivalent of Java's @Override?

Tags: c#, interface, overriding, abstract

This has been asked before, but I could not get clarity from that answer, that's why I ask again...

Let's use two examples:

1. class implements interface
2. class extends an abstract class

My feeling is that with respect to the `override` keyword, both samples must behave identically. What is the desired goal of `override`? To prevent a method being dropped in a superclass or interface without being changed in all subclasses or implementing classes. So a compile time code consistency check.

In this C# code, compiling results in error: '....RepositoryContext.getXmlDoc()': no suitable method found to override:

```
interface IRepositoryContext
{
    XmlDocument getXmlDoc();
}

class RepositoryContext : IRepositoryContext
{
     private readonly XmlDocument gXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

     public override XmlDocument getXmlDoc() // does not compile
     {    
        return gXmlDoc;
     }
}
```

Whereas in this C# code, compilation works without any errors or warnings:

```
abstract class RepositoryContextBase
{

     public abstract XmlDocument getXmlDoc();
}

class RepositoryContext : RepositoryContextBase
{
     private readonly XmlDocument gXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

     public override XmlDocument getXmlDoc()
     {    
        return gXmlDoc;
     }
}
```

Is it a valid assumption that this should not work identically, or is there a way around this, or...?

Answer (score 4):

The `override` modifier is defined thus:

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or virtual **implementation** of an **inherited** method, property, indexer, or event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx

The `override` keyword specifies that the method overrides an *existing* method implementation, which is why you don't need to specify it when you're implementing an interface directly - there is no such method to override; you're the first to implement it.

When you use the `override` keyword, you're essentially saying "for this class, call this method instead of the base method." This obviously doesn't apply when there is no such base method (e.g. when you are directly implementing an interface).

Answer (score 2):

For virtual or abstract methods from classes, you need to insert the `override` keyword or it won't work at all.

For interfaces, there is no equivalent.

However, interface implementations must implement all of their base methods, so forgetting a method will usually give you a compiler error.
This makes it less important.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example it's an interface you're implementing. You can't `override` something when *you're the only implementer* in the inheritance chain.

In the second example you've inherited from a concrete implementation and stated that you want to implement the `abstract` member and the syntax for that (albeit not literally an *override* as much as an *implementation*) is the `override` keyword. However, you are in fact *overriding* the chain you're a part of because you're *implementing* it.

So think of the *override* keyword more in relation to the fact that you're ensuring your implementation gets called *instead of* the base class when it's called on an instance of the inheritor.

This too explains why you must *explicitly call* `base.Member()` inside the `override` because you've *overriden* the chain.

Another OO concept to remember is that the same effect can be achieve on methods that *aren't* `abstract` or `virtual`. Members can in fact be *hidden* and you don't *have* to specify them with the `new` keyword.

With that being said it should help abstract for you the idea that these are very much *just language features* or maybe better said *it's just syntax.*

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are implementing an interface. In this case you do not have to specify the `override` keyword, simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a misconception regarding *interface implementation vs. inheritance*.

- Interface implementations are completely different from inheritance. With an interface, you statically (i.e. at compile time) enforce the presence of certain method signatures. Therefore, any keywords like override or the like are just plain wrong in such a context.
- Inheritance on the contrary is causing runtime polymorphism through a virtual method table (basically a list of method adresses).

You can see this also from the fact that, in C#, you can implement as many interfaces as you like, whereas multiple inheritance is forbidden.

Comment: To all: i have an answer: it is not there

Comment: And to all who think it is not relevant. It is relevant. I don't want to be ignorant, but if you are building a new application, it is easy to say : implement all methods from this interface through snippet or whatever. But if you have huge application where you change one interface method signature and there are many classes implementing multiple interfaces, this was in java for me the way to ensure that i do not forget changing / dropping a method in case i change the interface.

Comment: And @Thomas : interface implementations are different compared to abstract classes. But i deny to say that conceptually this is because the compiler wants to check method signatures ... No, the difference is conceptually that an interface only defines the responsibility whereas an abstract class can define how to implement that responsiblity. That is in my perception the conceptual difference. And from that angle, there is for me not a difference in  meaning for override.

Comment: but though, thanks a lot for the comments given above. I will go through them and explore hidden, etc. thanks!!

Comment: @ddjong Nice to see that you have a perception. But note that it may differ largely from the facts...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is a fundamental difference between *implementing an interface* and *overriding a method*.

In order to fully implement an interface, you have to provide implementations for all of methods and/or properties but those implementations do not necessarily have to be overrideable in turn. The compiler wants you to be very specific about your intentions when you create a method, because you may have one of a range of behaviours in mind, and it wants to be sure which one you mean.

The [`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) keyword means "I am overriding the base class' implementation with this one". If when implementing an interface, there is no base implementation, then it doesn't apply. You use `virtual` to indicate an overrideable method with no base implementation, and omit both `override` and `virtual` otherwise.

So given this interface:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
```

This class implements that interface, and permits classes to inherit from it in turn and override that implementation (since unlike in e.g. Java, methods in C# are not virtual by default):

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public virtual void Bar() { ... } // compiles
}

class DerivedFoo : Foo
{
    public override void Bar() { ... } // compiles, and may choose to call base.Bar()
}
```

Whereas this class implements that interface, and does not permit overrides:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Bar(); // compiles
}

class DerivedFoo : Foo
{
    public override void Bar() { ... } // does NOT compile; Foo.Bar() is not virtual (overrideable)
}
```

There are in fact more possiblities than that, including:

- You can create an [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) base class which implements an interface, but only provide abstract implementations for some/all methods.
- You can [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) implement an interface method
- You can [seal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) an overriding method to prevent further overrides
- You can create a [new method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) with the same name which is unrelated to the base class' method of that name

There are [more details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39.aspx).

If you aren't specific enough for the compiler, it will warn you or throw an error.

**Update**

The reason the compiler complains in the second example above, is that you will not get polymorphic behaviour. That is, if someone has a reference to `Foo` and calls `Bar()`, they will get `Foo`'s implementation, not `DerivedFoo`'s. This is because `Bar.Foo` is not in the virtual method table. Put another way, in C#, the default when compared to Java is that all methods are `final` unless you say otherwise.

From your comments it sounds like you're trying to get a warning or error in the case where, in my first example above, you then change `IFoo` by removing the `Bar` method entirely. (Obviously if you just change the method signature, you'll get a suitable compile error as you'd hope.)

You can achieve this by [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) implementing the method:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.Bar() { ... }
}
```

Then if the interface changes, you will get a compile error. However, this means derived classes can no longer override Foo's implementation; if you want that behaviour as well, you need:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.Bar() { ... }

    protected /* or public */ virtual void Bar()
    {
        IFoo foo = this; // declare rather than cast, to get compile error not runtime exception
        foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

You will still get compile errors if you remove the method, both from your explicit and other implementation.

Bear in mind that the explicit implementation is only available to callers with a reference to an IFoo, not a Foo. But if as in the above code you do add a public method which, for example, delegates to the explicit IFoo implementation, that won't be a problem (and it doesn't have to be virtual unless you want it overrideable).

This is an approach that works; whether it's overkill is a matter of taste, but I can see the merit in removing redundant code as part of refactoring, provided the classes are not public and/or not used outside your assembly. However instead of factoring code in this fashion I'd recommend using a tool such as [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which will warn you about unused methods.

Comment: Thanks El Zorko .. you make me think(!, thanks for that) ... i will play with it and revert back on this ... I hope tomorrow/day after.

Comment: Can I ask what you not convinced by? My explanation (which I could understand), or why C# requires these keywords in these situations (which I could also understand, as it's just a language design choice)?

Comment: oef, i had written some coment in word, but can only be 600 chars :(

Comment: Part 1: Trying to read what you said: 
Quote: 
The C# language is designed so that versioning between base and derived classes  can evolve and maintain backward compatibility. Eg. that the introduction of a new member in a base class with the same name as a member in a derived class is completely supported by C# and does not lead to unexpected behavior. It also means that a class must explicitly state whether:
   1. method is intended to override an inherited => use 'override'.
   2. method is a new method that hides super.sameMethod => use 'new'.

Comment: ----- Part 2:   @your remark (1): 
override method <> implement interface: 
Sure that is 100% true. Conceptually for me : implement an interface means to me : be able to behave like ... (polymorphism). A class (e.g. HumanBeing, can implement multiple interfaces : IEmployee, IHusband, IChoirMember, ...) where it is the same implementation class possibly (theory but can be done). 
Whereas override method is either usually done when overriding the implementation. Bcz if signature cannot be changed, what is use of overriding an interface method in a sub-interface?
------

Comment: Part 3: @your remark (2):
Sealing, abstract, virtual, i recognize most of that from e.g. Java (final, abstract, ...). I see your code sample DerivedFoo -> Foo -> IFoo. 
What is the reason that override on DerivedFoo must throw a warning? that must be related to the intention of keyword 'override'. If i read the quote above it is to ensure that it has a definition in its 'super' for this method. In any case you change this Foo class it will throw an error (correct, rit?).

Comment: Part 4: But when i drop the method 'public void Bar() from the interface there is no compiler that triggers me that i may need to drop method void Bar() from Foo, rit?
And that is what override could do, even in case of interfaces, or? I am not saying: It must be done according the spec. There you are right. But i am saying: the question is a relevant question, and in java this is covered with the @Override, where in .Net you must not use / cannot use override for this situation.

Comment: Part 5 (last): Summarizing:
a- for me it would help if there is some mechanism to trigger me to drop methods from implementation classes if it is dropped from the interface.
b- i agree that this is not the objective of keyword 'override'
c- i would luv if that could be done in another way (ensuring this a.) ;)

Comment: just small remark: in all my applications, all my classes implement an interface and my method parameters are always interfaces and never the implementation class .. reason: in java you have single inheritance and i do not want to be hindered by an implementation in any method signature ... and that is what an interface does : specify the contract only ...  (but i know: this is just a personal preference (blush))

Comment: maybe little 'purist' but i like this approach

Comment: If you use "override" when the base method is not virtual or override, the compiler will complain because you won't get polymorphic behaviour (the original method isn't in the vtable). It's as if in Java you had marked the base method as "final": in C# this is the default unless you say otherwise. If you want a specific warning that you should remove an implementation when the interface changes, you can use an explicit implementation, though the method will only then be accessible via IFoo not via Foo. I'll update my answer to note that.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope that helps; if you feel this answers your question sufficiently, please do mark it as the answer.

Comment: question has already been marked as 'answered'. But thanks for the help! really appreciated.

Comment: So you know, on Stack Overflow it's customary to accept one answer as the "correct" answer if you feel it is such (there's a box next to each answer). And to upvote any answers you feel are helpful of course. But no worries either way.